# How can I reset timer of dropwizard metrics?

Tags: timer, dropwizard, metrics, codahale-metrics

We are processing messages that comes in periodically. We use codahale dropwizard metrics' "Timer" for measuring the time it takes to process them.

I found someone had the same issue [here](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/issues/143):
"problem with exponentially decaying reservoir is that if no new data comes in, it will keep on giving the same numbers all the times. For example, let say you update a timer with 5 and 7 (then don't put anything at all) , then no matter when you see (even after x hours), timer will still show the average to be 6 which is not representative of last 5 mins by any means.
so, it works only if data is arriving all the time."

As you can see with the dark blue line: 
[image]

But there's no suggestion to solve it. And they say it's not going to be implemented: https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/issues/399

How can I reset these timers properly or how should I visualize it so it's not confusing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Note: It is too long for comment.
```

Using the `SlidingTimeWindowReservoir` will cover most of the use-cases.
But as pointed out in [this comment](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/issues/143#issuecomment-63345927) there could be a problem depending on the number of events:
it keeps all the measurements in the window in-memory which becomes unacceptable at large number of events

Could we do better? Let's continue searching. If we are lucky we will find [this blog post](http://taint.org/2014/01/16/145944a.html). It describes exactly your kind of problem. There is a link to their simple dirty solution. Also a suggestion for using [HdrHistogram](http://hdrhistogram.org/).

Also on the [metrics mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/metrics-user) there are several messages about exactly this problem.
For [example](https://groups.google.com/forum/?_escaped_fragment_=topic/metrics-user/90oRLlDTNWU#!topic/metrics-user/90oRLlDTNWU) and point to [Marshall Pierce/hdrhistogram-metrics-reservoir](https://bitbucket.org/marshallpierce/hdrhistogram-metrics-reservoir). What is `HdrHistogram` and why use it to measure latencies check the project description.

And finally after some more digging you could find also [vladimir-bukhtoyarov/metrics-core-hdr](https://github.com/vladimir-bukhtoyarov/metrics-core-hdr/blob/master/histograms.md)
 project. It's using `HdrHistogram` also.

So there are two similar libraries that use the same data structure and claim to solve the problem case you have hit.

Comment: your answer is much more detailed than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate timer by using
public boolean remove(String name) of com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry
(pass timer name as parameter here) each time you need to reset.
After removing you create a new timer with the same name. It will have zero counter & other metrics.