# Instrumenting JVM code to submit timers and counters to AWS CloudWatch

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jvm, dropwizard

How do you instrument timers and counters in JVM code such that they are passed to AWS CloudWatch? I am interested in manual instrumentation, e.g.: adding `timer.start()`, `timer.stop()`, and `counter.incr()` calls where desired.

Our current solution is to use [Dropwizard Metrics](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/) for the instrumentation, and [this project](https://github.com/blacklocus/metrics-cloudwatch) does a great job of sending the metrics to AWS. The problem with this stack is that Dropwizard Metrics has its own internal aggregates that are based on a [expontentially decaying reservoir](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/blob/9cd8f5b03285515cab6e98d49bb314cb3dd952f3/metrics-core/src/main/java/com/codahale/metrics/ExponentiallyDecayingReservoir.java). As others have mentioned, this behavior is [not easily modified](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/issues/730). The result is confusing and incorrect data in AWS Cloudwatch. For example:

- Averages slowly creep toward the actual value, resulting in a sloped line where a flat line is expected
- Min and max values get temporarily stuck at some prior value, resulting in a perfect flat line where a continuously changing value is expected

I think a better solution might be to aggregate no more than a minute of data before submitting it to AWS.

Comment: See my comment/answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40809650/25429